# React Admin how to resolve an url into a field

Tags: reactjs, django, api, react-hooks, react-admin

I'm new with react admin and I'm tring to figure out how can I resolve an url in an Custom field. I am usin Django Rest Framework as my backend application and it returns this:

```
{
  "id": "PwybRVej1r3L2Ag7smAvpqW45076GzZd",
  "unity": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/unity/n7VzbMW25rYZLB17SZ9Rl8eXqE36QDxk/",
  "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/truck/PwybRVej1r3L2Ag7smAvpqW45076GzZd/",
  "created": "2022-08-08T23:48:32.876117Z",
  "modified": "2022-08-08T23:48:32.876117Z",
  "license_plate": "ADS-8974"
},
```

And I'm using JWT as the authentication standard. In this way I found [ra-data-django-rest-framework](https://github.com/bmihelac/ra-data-django-rest-framework). For simple cases, the usage is simply straightforward. But I'm trying to create a field that can resolve the url("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/unity/n7VzbMW25rYZLB17SZ9Rl8eXqE36QDxk/") and returns the information I need. Does anyone know how it could be resolved?

I tried this without success:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useRecordContext, useGetOne } from 'react-admin';

const UnityField = ({ source }) => {
    const record = useRecordContext();
    const unity = useGetOne(record[source]);
    console.log(unity)
    return record ? (
        <a href={record[source]}>
            {unity}
        </a>
    ) : null;
}

export default UnityField;
```

Answer (score 0):

React-admin provides an `<UrlField>`, does it work in your case?

```
<UrlField source="unity" />
```

See https://marmelab.com/react-admin/UrlField.html for details